# Empty HTML in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Rails is returning blank HTML when running in production.

The tests I describe bellow are done with the following line: `wget http://localhost:3000/login -O here.txt ; cat here.txt`. I expect see some HTML being output after executing it.

On my server, I can see the HTML being rendered when I start rails in development mode, using the command `rails s`. I can see the following in the log:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-21 18:30:32 +0000
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered user_sessions/_login.html.haml (59.5ms)
  Rendered user_sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (62.8ms)
Compiled bootstrap-datepicker.css  (0ms)  (pid 8050)
Compiled application.css  (4ms)  (pid 8050)
Compiled bootstrap.min.css  (0ms)  (pid 8050)
 # lots of Compiled lines
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1404ms (Views: 1395.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

When starting my application with `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`, doing the same request, I got the following on the log:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-21 18:30:52 +0000
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered user_sessions/_login.html.haml (57.8ms)
  Rendered user_sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (60.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

But no HTML is output. What is happening? Why this is not working the same way that it does on development?

I use `rails 3.2.13`, and in this test it runs with `WEBrick`. I also am using `RVM` if that matters.

**Update: Using the content of `config/environments/development.rb` on `config/environments/production.rb` does not fix the problem**

Comment: have u precompiled the assets for production environment?

Comment: @AmanGarg Yes, and also I have `config.serve_static_assets = true` for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was rescuing an exception on ApplicationController and not handling it properly by a logical error. The exception was not raised on development mode.